# How to increase MKMarkerAnnotationView touch and drag area?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I show `MKMarkerAnnotationView` annotations on a `MKMapView`. When selected they can be dragged / moved by long pressing and then moving the annotation. This is how an annotation looks like when selected:

[image: MKMarkerAnnotationView example image]

To start the dragging the user has to tap and hold until the annotation switches into the dragging state. All this functionality is provided by MapKit.

**The issue**: The user has to tap and hold *right at the bottom of the red bubble* to start the dragging process. If he tries to do that somewhere at the top of the bubble it does not work. This is very annoying for users of the app because they do not understand why dragging does not work. They expect the whole bubble area to be touch sensitive for the drag gesture.

How can I increase the touch sensitive area for the tap and hold => drag gesture to make it more intuitive?

Comment: I know this should probably be fixed by Apple in `MapKit` however I am curious if there is a workaround maybe so I do not have to wait for Apple to address this issue.

Comment: Supply your own annotation view?